# EC2 outbound requests are in IPv6 causing connection timeout if server doesn't have AAAA record

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-web-services

I created an AWS VPC and security group with the necessary outbound rules and routes to an internet gateway for IPv4 and IPv6. I created an autoscaling group, but the important part is I have an Ubuntu 22 EC2 instance that can run `wget https://google.com` properly:

```
ubuntu@ip-10-0-0-0:~$ wget https://google.com
--2023-03-20 20:43:26--  https://google.com/
Resolving google.com (google.com)... 2607:f8b0:4004:c06::66, 2607:f8b0:4004:c06::64, 2607:f8b0:4004:c06::8b, ...
Connecting to google.com (google.com)|2607:f8b0:4004:c06::66|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 301 Moved Permanently
Location: https://www.google.com/ [following]
--2023-03-20 20:43:27--  https://www.google.com/
Resolving www.google.com (www.google.com)... 2607:f8b0:4004:c1b::69, 2607:f8b0:4004:c1b::67, 2607:f8b0:4004:c1b::93, ...
Connecting to www.google.com (www.google.com)|2607:f8b0:4004:c1b::69|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: unspecified [text/html]
Saving to: ‘index.html.4’

index.html.4                        [ <=>                                                 ]  13.90K  --.-KB/s    in 0s      

2023-03-20 20:43:27 (184 MB/s) - ‘index.html.4’ saved [14231]
```

but it can't connect to a website that doesn't have AAAA record or one that accepts IPv6 like stackoverflow: https://ready.chair6.net/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com

It just hangs:

```
wget https://stackoverflow.com
--2023-03-20 20:45:40--  https://stackoverflow.com/
Resolving stackoverflow.com (stackoverflow.com)... 64:ff9b::9765:4145, 64:ff9b::9765:145, 64:ff9b::9765:c145, ...
Connecting to stackoverflow.com (stackoverflow.com)|64:ff9b::9765:4145|:443...
```

eventually it'll get there, but I'm not sure how to fix it? I feel like I've covered all grounds... (reason this is an issue is because the AWS CodeDeploy agent isn't able to validate SSL certificate; here's that error:

```
2023-03-20 19:44:32 INFO  [codedeploy-agent(13669)]: master 13669: Spawned child 1/1
2023-03-20 19:44:32 INFO  [codedeploy-agent(13671)]: On Premises config file does not exist or not readable
2023-03-20 19:44:32 INFO  [codedeploy-agent(13671)]: CodeDeploy endpoint: https://codedeploy-commands.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
2023-03-20 19:44:32 INFO  [codedeploy-agent(13671)]: InstanceAgent::Plugins::CodeDeployPlugin::CommandExecutor: Archives to retain is: 5}
2023-03-20 19:44:32 INFO  [codedeploy-agent(13671)]: CodeDeploy endpoint: https://codedeploy-commands.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
2023-03-20 19:44:32 INFO  [codedeploy-agent(13671)]: CodeDeploy endpoint: https://codedeploy-commands.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
2023-03-20 19:44:33 INFO  [codedeploy-agent(13669)]: Started master 13669 with 1 children
2023-03-20 19:45:32 ERROR [codedeploy-agent(13671)]: InstanceAgent::Plugins::CodeDeployPlugin::CodeDeployControl: Error during certificate verification on codedeploy endpoint https://codedeploy-commands.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
2023-03-20 19:45:32 ERROR [codedeploy-agent(13671)]: Error validating the SSL configuration: Invalid server certificate
2023-03-20 19:45:32 ERROR [codedeploy-agent(13671)]: booting child: error during start or run: SystemExit - Stopping CodeDeploy agent due to SSL validation error. - /opt/codedeploy-agent/lib/instance_agent/plugins/codedeploy/command_poller.rb:65:in `abort'
/opt/codedeploy-agent/lib/instance_agent/plugins/codedeploy/command_poller.rb:65:in `validate'
/opt/codedeploy-agent/lib/instance_agent/agent/base.rb:11:in `runner'
/opt/codedeploy-agent/lib/instance_agent/runner/child.rb:32:in `block in prepare_run'
/opt/codedeploy-agent/lib/instance_agent/runner/child.rb:78:in `with_error_handling'
/opt/codedeploy-agent/lib/instance_agent/runner/child.rb:31:in `prepare_run'
/opt/codedeploy-agent/vendor/gems/process_manager-0.0.13/lib/process_manager/child.rb:64:in `block in prepare_run_with_error_handling'
/opt/codedeploy-agent/lib/instance_agent/runner/child.rb:78:in `with_error_handling'
/opt/codedeploy-agent/vendor/gems/process_manager-0.0.13/lib/process_manager/child.rb:63:in `prepare_run_with_error_handling'
/opt/codedeploy-agent/vendor/gems/process_manager-0.0.13/lib/process_manager/child.rb:20:in `start'
/opt/codedeploy-agent/vendor/gems/process_manager-0.0.13/lib/process_manager/master.rb:206:in `block in spawn_child'
```

The EC2 instance has an assigned public IPv4 address and IPv6 address, and it's in a public subnet. Anyone have ideas on what could be going wrong? Greatly appreciate it:)

- Other options I'm thinking about is figuring out how to just completely disable IPv6 outbound requests while still being able to accept IPv6 inbound via my network + application load balancer.

Answer (score 0):

Not a complete answer, but I just turned off auto-assign IPv6 to my public subnet and re-ran codedeploy

Comment: Disabling ipv6 is a workaround rather than a solution. Your question isn't really very clear, if you want an answer that works with IPv6 you'll need to provide more detail about the problem.